# Dynamics CRM 2016: Do not retrieving account id using XRM Service Tool kit

Tags: accounts, dynamics-crm-2016, xrmservicetoolkit

In following code snippet I am trying to get child accounts if parent account id matched. It is populating the account name as expected such as `ABC Title Company` or `Test Tile Co.` but it populates account id as `undefined`.

I [XRM Service Toolkit](https://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Soap%20Functions) for retrieving the details of child account at CRM 2016. I don't know what went wrong in case of account id I double checked the spellings of the attribute but nothing get in favor.

```
functiongetChildAccounts(pAccountId)
{
var query =
            "<a:ColumnSet>" +
            "<a:AllColumns>false</a:AllColumns>" +
            "<a:Columns xmlns:b='http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'>" +
            "<b:string>name</b:string>" +
            "<b:string>accountid</b:string>" +
          "</a:Columns>" +
        "</a:ColumnSet>" +
        "<a:Criteria>" +
          "<a:Conditions />" +
          "<a:FilterOperator>And</a:FilterOperator>" +
          "<a:Filters>" +
"<a:FilterExpression>" +
  "<a:Conditions>" +
    "<a:ConditionExpression>" +
      "<a:AttributeName>parentaccountid</a:AttributeName>" +
      "<a:Operator>Equal</a:Operator>" +
      "<a:Values xmlns:b='http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'>" +
        "<b:anyType i:type='c:string' xmlns:c='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>"+ pAccountId +"</b:anyType>" +
      "</a:Values>" +
    "</a:ConditionExpression>" +
  "</a:Conditions>" +
  "<a:FilterOperator>And</a:FilterOperator>" +
  "<a:Filters />" +
"</a:FilterExpression>" +
          "</a:Filters>" +
        "</a:Criteria>" +
        "<a:Distinct>false</a:Distinct>" +
        "<a:EntityName>account</a:EntityName>" +
        "<a:LinkEntities />" +
        "<a:Orders />" +
        "<a:PageInfo>" +
          "<a:Count>0</a:Count>" +
          "<a:PageNumber>0</a:PageNumber>" +
          "<a:PagingCookie i:nil='true' />" +
          "<a:ReturnTotalRecordCount>false</a:ReturnTotalRecordCount>" +
        "</a:PageInfo>" +
        "<a:NoLock>false</a:NoLock>";

        var childAccounts = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.RetrieveMultiple(query);

        alert(childAccounts[0].attributes['name'].value);
        alert(childAccounts[0].attributes['accountid'].id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your piece of code you can use something like this, because is going to give you the id of the account.

alert(childAccounts[0].id);

You can use the debug and put a watch to get expression of the value.