# XRMService Toolkit not matching parent account guid with another guid stored in a single line text field

Tags: javascript, guid, contacts, accounts, dynamics-crm-2016

I've a hidden field on order form that store guid of parent account of selected contact. Now, in following code snippet I am trying to compare an account guid with that stored in hidden field. But it is returning zero length.

```
function getOrdersDetail(accountId)
{
var query =
                     "<a:ColumnSet>" +
                      "<a:AllColumns>false</a:AllColumns>" +
                      "<a:Columns xmlns:b='http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'>" +
                        "<b:string>createdon</b:string>" +
                      "</a:Columns>" +
                    "</a:ColumnSet>" +
                    "<a:Criteria>" +
                      "<a:Conditions />" +
                      "<a:FilterOperator>And</a:FilterOperator>" +
                      "<a:Filters>" +
                        "<a:FilterExpression>" +
                          "<a:Conditions>" +
                            "<a:ConditionExpression>" +
                              "<a:AttributeName>new_accountid</a:AttributeName>" +
                              "<a:Operator>Equal</a:Operator>" +
                              "<a:Values xmlns:b='http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'>" +
                                "<b:anyType i:type='c:string' xmlns:c='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>"+ accountId +"</b:anyType>" +
                              "</a:Values>" +
                            "</a:ConditionExpression>" +
                          "</a:Conditions>" +
                          "<a:FilterOperator>And</a:FilterOperator>" +
                          "<a:Filters />" +
                        "</a:FilterExpression>" +
                      "</a:Filters>" +
                    "</a:Criteria>" +
                    "<a:Distinct>false</a:Distinct>" +
                    "<a:EntityName>salesorder</a:EntityName>" +
                    "<a:LinkEntities />" +
                    "<a:Orders/>" +
                    "<a:PageInfo>" +
                      "<a:Count>0</a:Count>" +
                      "<a:PageNumber>0</a:PageNumber>" +
                      "<a:PagingCookie i:nil='true' />" +
                      "<a:ReturnTotalRecordCount>false</a:ReturnTotalRecordCount>" +
                    "</a:PageInfo>" +
                    "<a:NoLock>false</a:NoLock>";

        var orders = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.RetrieveMultiple(query);

        alert(orders.length);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamics CRM 2016: Do not retrieving account id using XRM Service Tool kit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37190236/dynamics-crm-2016-do-not-retrieving-account-id-using-xrm-service-tool-kit) Please close this question and edit your original instead

Comment: I've edited question and it is not similar to that you have mentioned.

Comment: Get your query working in Advanced Find, download the fetch, and then use `XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Fetch(fetchXml)`.